# Can't access tomcat 9 gui in Debian 9 machine

Tags: linux, tomcat, debian

I installed tomcat 9.0.10 in my Debian machine. But the problem is I couldn't use the manager ui of the tomcat. I'm using jdk1.8.0_162. I'm able to start the tomcat by /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh and it is giving the following output in the terminal.

```html
root@debian:/usr/jdk1.8.0_162/jre/bin# /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/jdk1.8.0_*/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

But when I try to access the http://localhost:8080/manager/html

I'm getting 404 error.

I checked the catalina.out file and found the below line.

> /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: /usr/jdk1.8.0_*/jre/bin/java: not found

Here is my setenv.sh file

```html
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_*
export JRE_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_*/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Can some body help me to resolve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: of course * is a problem here

Comment: @EugèneAdell Yes, you are right. The * symbol was the problem i removed this and put the version number. Now it is working. Thanks